# SharePoint Search REST API: what does IsMissingUnifiedGroups mean?

Tags: search, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

When using the SharePoint search REST API, we see:

```
  "Properties": [
      ...omitted,
          {
            "Key": "IsMissingUnifiedGroups",
            "Value": "true",
            "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean"
          },
  ]
```

in the response, which is worrying.

What does this property mean? Does it mean that there are unified groups missing from the results? If so, what can I do to make them show up?

I've tried adding EnableDynamicGroups: true to our request but it doesn't help.

```
curl -v -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -G "https://${SITE_URL}/_api/Search/Query" --data-urlencode "QueryText='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'" --data-urlencode "EnableStemming=false" --data-urlencode "TrimDuplicates=false" --data-urlencode "RowLimit=300" --data "Properties='ClientFunction:AllResults,EnableDynamicGroups:true'"
```